# How to use spring Repository without @Id?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

I'm using spring `CrudRepository` throughout my application.
Now I want to also create one for an `@Entity` that does not have an `@Id`. Is that possible at all?

```
//probably ID is always required?
public interface Repository<T, ID extends Serializable>
```

Comment: do you mean that your entity doesn't have an id at all or it is some kind of embedded structure? Could you show your entity code?

Comment: if your entities in your database don't have a PRIMARY KEY (ID), then you've got bigger problems.

Comment: Are you able to fix it? Could you please update the answer.

Comment: @bpa.mdl it's simply not possible, as stated in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

JPA requires that every entity has an ID. So no, entity w/o an ID is not allowed.

> Every JPA entity must have a primary key.

from [JPA spec](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/cmp30cfg001.htm)

You may want to read more about how JPA handles a case when there's no id on the DB side [from here (see 'No Primary Key')](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#No_Primary_Key).

Comment: use all of the columns as the id does't work in hibernate if any column is null

Answer (score 3):

## Use **@IdClass** (composite key)

Yes, this is possible. This approach can be used when you read from a DB view. The below example demonstrates how to mark all *(2, in the given example)* columns as the composite ID:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import lombok.Data;          // auto-generates  AllArgs contractor, getters/setters, equals, and hashcode 

@Data
@Entity
@IdClass(MyEntity.class)                         // <--this is the extra annotation to add
@Table(name = "my_table")
public class MyEntity implements Serializable{   // <--this is the extra interface to add
  @Id                                            // annotate each column with @Id
  private String column1;

  @Id                                            // annotate each column with @Id
  private String column2;
}
```

- The above **MyEntity** uses the full record state as the key:
- --so, in addition to @EqualsAndHashcode, do flag the class with **Serializable** interface;
- --annotate each field with **@ID**
- In your <T, ID> repository say the ID is your full (entity) class:

---

```
interface MyEntityRepo extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, MyEntity> {
                                                        // ^^^the full record is the ID
```

---

See also:

1. [docs.oracle.com - Example 7.4-7.5: Non-Embedded Composite Primary Key](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/cmp30cfg001.htm#sthref793)
2. [baeldung.com/jpa-composite-primary-keys](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-composite-primary-keys#idclass), for more fine-grained custom IdClass, with fewer (than all) columns in the ID.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can extend `AbstractPersistable<Long>` for your all POJO entities.

Follow example: - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/jpa/example/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/simple/User.java

Comment: It will create an Id column in the table.