# Can I use CRUDRepository to update an entity holding only one field?

Tags: java, spring-boot, crud

I have a class named Genre (a @Entity), having only one field "name" (which is also id), in my Spring Boot application. It works fine, but now I realized - maybe I can't use the CRUDRepository to update a genre...

Since if I send in an altered Genre to genreRepository.save() - how can it find it? Can I make my own query to update it by name? Or must I add a new Id-field to the entity?

Greetings Val

Comment: A table with only one field makes no sense. It is only a list. How would you reference from other entities? You should re-think your design, or explain more detailled what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is I advice you to reconsider your design since it only contains one column "name", to my understanding normally you might not want to use the string as a primary key,  I think its better to use a separate column such as "ID" which will uniquely identify each row in a table, when you do that there are bunch of options provided in the spring boot and then using Spring CRUD Repository make more sense

Comment: Thanks @Aditya gupta, and I forgot to write that the name field was also the Id field, it is a little unflexible to just have one field I realized.

Answer (score 0):

As answered already in this Question 
([How to use spring Repository without @Id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29561885/how-to-use-spring-repository-without-id)) 
JPA requires that every entity has an ID.