# Why is the JpaRepository.findAll() method fetching the wrong data from my Oracle database?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot

My Spring Boot application fetches the wrong data from my Oracle database, as in It retrieves the right amount of rows but the content is not correct (data is missing, other rows are [propably] duplicated).

I'm new to Spring Boot and Oracle Databases. I read a lot of Tutorials and coded along. Now i try to create my first prototype of a webservice that fetches data from an Oracle 12c Database and makes them accessible via an HTTP Endpoint.

I use SQL Developer to check the content of the table i want to display and it shows different stuff then in my Spring Boot application. 
I use Spring Boot 2.1.4.

The table I want to display contains information about daily running cronjobs.

This is the **Controller**

```java
import de.dat.verguetung.entity.DailyJobsEntity;
import de.dat.verguetung.service.DailyJobsService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import java.util.List;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dailyjobs")
public class DailyJobsController {
    @Autowired
    DailyJobsService dailyJobsService;

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<DailyJobsEntity> getAllDailyJobs() {
        return dailyJobsService.getAllDailyJobs();
    }
}
```

This is my **Repository Interface**

```java
import de.prototype.entity.DailyJobsEntity;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface DailyJobsRepository extends JpaRepository<DailyJobsEntity, Integer> {
}
```

This is my **model**

```java
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "LOG_DAILY_JOBS")
public class DailyJobsEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "JOB_TITLE", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String jobTitle;

    @Column(name = "OK", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private Integer ok;

    @Column(name = "JOB_RESULT", nullable = true, length = 1000)
    private String jobResult;

    @Column(name = "EXECUTION_DATE", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date executionDate;


    protected DailyJobsEntity() {}

    public DailyJobsEntity(String jobTitle, Integer ok, String jobResult, Date executionDate) {
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
        this.ok = ok;
        this.jobResult = jobResult;
        this.executionDate = executionDate;
    }

    public Date getExecutionDate() {return executionDate;}

    public void setExecutionDate(Date executionDate) {this.executionDate = executionDate;}

    public String getJobResult() {return jobResult;}

    public void setJobResult(String jobResult) {this.jobResult = jobResult;}

    public Integer getOk() {return ok;}

    public void setOk(Integer ok) {this.ok = ok;}

    public String getJobTitle() {return jobTitle;}

    public void setJobTitle(String jobTitle) {this.jobTitle = jobTitle;}
}
```

This is my **Service**

```java
import de.dat.verguetung.dao.DailyJobsRepository;
import de.dat.verguetung.entity.DailyJobsEntity;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class DailyJobsService {
    @Autowired
    DailyJobsRepository dailyJobsRepository;

    public List<DailyJobsEntity> getAllDailyJobs(){
        return this.dailyJobsRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

And this is my **Main Class**

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class VerguetungApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(VerguetungApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The table has 156 rows. The application fetches 156 rows. Thats fine. 
But 95% of these rows are filled with the wrong content. 
I have a column named 'EXECUTION_DATE'. 
The entries for this column range from 2019-04-02 until 2019-04-16. 
The application displays every row with an execution date of 2019-04-02.

I can provide more details about the content of the table if needed.

I hope someone can help my and point out my mistakes. 
Thanks in advance :)

**Edit:** 
This is the content in the table:

```
58  1   58  02.04.19
58  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   58  02.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  0   ORA-01403: Keine Daten gefunden 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  0   ORA-01403: Keine Daten gefunden 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   146 03.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   85  04.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   76  05.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   23  15.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   96  16.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   96  16.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   96  16.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   96  16.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   96  16.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   96  16.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   96  16.04.19
get_vsu_movement_count  1   96  16.04.19
```

And this what gets displayed by the application

```
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
58 | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
58 | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
get_vsu_movement_count | 1 | 58 | 2019-04-02
```

**Edit 2**
The code for printing the fetched rows

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dailyjobs")
public class DailyJobsController {
    @Autowired
    DailyJobsService dailyJobsService;

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<DailyJobsEntity> getAllDailyJobs() {
        List<DailyJobsEntity> dJobs = dailyJobsService.getAllDailyJobs();

        dJobs.stream().forEach(job -> {
            System.out.println(job.getJobTitle() + " | " + job.getOk() + " | " + job.getJobResult() + " | " + job.getExecutionDate());
        });
        System.out.println(dJobs.size());
        return dJobs;
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that the bug is in the way you display the values in the application. What is the output of `curl http://localhost:8080/dailyjobs/all`? Or what happens when you print every date in your service of controller?

Comment: Is incorrect data only for  EXECUTION_DATE or other columns/rows as well?

Comment: @JBNizet I added the output if i print every fetched row in the controller.

Comment: @Abhijeet Every column displays incorrect data

Comment: Then you're probably not using the same database/schema/table in your app and in your SQL tool. Or you have made modifications in your SQL tool and have not committed them yet. Or you're not printing everything correctly (you haven't posted the code)

Comment: @JBNizet I added the code for printing the fetched rows

Comment: Ah. So now the problem is clear: all your entities have the same ID. An ID is supposed to be unique, like a primary key in a database. It's used to **identify** (hence the name, ID) the entity.

Comment: Yes. That is in fact the problem.
Thank you for taking your time with my problem :) 
In the answer below i asked the question how can i use every column as an Id and how that is meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, your DailyJobsRepository uses `DailyJobsRepository extends JpaRepository<DailyJobsEntity, Integer>` to indicate that the primary key ID is of type `Integer`, while your entity `DailyJobsEntity` defines the ID to be of type String:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "JOB_TITLE", nullable = false, length = 100)
private String jobTitle;`
```

Is jobTitle the primary key of the entity? Because I would expect the PK to be of type  Integer.

Comment: I changed the DailyJobsRepository to
`DailyJobsRepository extends JpaRepository<DailyJobsEntity, String>`
This did not change the output. 

The table has no primary key (I did not create this table, my job is to display it). 
Can this be a problem?

Comment: Setting the ID type to `String` doesn't matter much, as the string keys used in your table dump are not unique. This post might be able to help you out further: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29561885/how-to-use-spring-repository-without-id

Comment: Okay I read the post and read some follow up information. One way to solve my problem would be to use "All columns as the id". 
Does that mean I have to annotate every field in my entity class with @Id?