# using spring data jpa repository if there is no primary key

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Iam working on a project where i have view of a database table which is exposed by the other team and other teams are also using that view.
Iam using spring data jpa in the project..

The view exposed to us does not have a primary key.

if there is no primary key how should my ViewRepository interface be declared..

I have a view which contains many values and i have created the entity as follows

```
package com.mf.acrs.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="mv_garage_master")
public class GarageMaster {

    @Column(name="GARAGE_CODE")
    private String garageCode;

    @Column(name="GARAGE_NAME")
    private String garageName;

    @Column(name="GARAGE_BRANCH")
    private String garageBranch; 


}
```

the repository interface is as follows:

```
package com.mf.acrs.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.mf.acrs.model.GarageMaster;

@Repository
public interface GarageMasterRepository extends JpaRepository<GarageMaster,ID>{
}
```

My question is what value should go in **ID** in the above interface..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use spring Repository without @Id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29561885/how-to-use-spring-repository-without-id)

Comment: Hi @tin_tin, I added a possible solution for you.

Comment: If it is view  then you could solve this problem by a simple trick you can add unique identifier as current row number in your view then you can use the row number in your Spring Data entity

Comment: This suggestion from @Govind Parashar  is ok and dangerous. Because it is a provided view, the entries can change and a record with id 4 can now be a different entry due to a insert in the database.

Comment: @Brother : Agree Its a bad from a design perspective. View generally read-only. If you don't have unique columns then you can not figure out the composite key then

Comment: @tin_tin Updated the answer with your information about the garageCode been unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, Entity, JPA and Spring Data needs you to have the ID, that is how the entity is found or updated.

[UPDATED] @tintin if the garageCode is unique according to your comment, you can achieve like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="mv_garage_master")
public class GarageMaster implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="GARAGE_CODE")
    private String garageCode;

    @Column(name="GARAGE_NAME")
    private String garageName;

    @Column(name="GARAGE_BRANCH")
    private String garageBranch; 
}
```

And the repository:

```
@Repository
public interface GarageMasterRepository extends JpaRepository<GarageMaster,String>{
}
```

Comment: in my example only garage_code is unique. how can i modify your solution to work in that situations.

Comment: Oh ok, so you have a field that is unique. Than this still works for you but it is an "overkill". I will modify the solution after but mainly you move the fields from the Id class I created to the main class, and add an annotation @Id on top of garageCode and in the repository, the id will be String instead of GarageMasterId and you can delete this class.

Comment: thanks your solution worked.. just one question the code works fine even if i don't add "implements Serializable". what is the purpose of this serializable?

Comment: hI @tin_tin I am glad that it worked! So about Serializable, normally for entities or objects send through web services/rest or persisted in DB it is recommended for some reasons, and here it is a brief explanation about it: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/serialization-in-java/