# How to create Spring Entity and Repository without primary key

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a table with two columns `user_id` and `role_id`. There's no unique column in table and I can't add one. How can I create `Entity` and `Repository` in Spring without a *primary key*?

This is my **UserRole.class**

```
public class UserRole {
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int userId;
    
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    private int roleId;


    //getters and setters
}
```

But with this class i get the following error:

> nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity:

I saw that one of the answers is to use all of the columns as the id, but i have no idea how to do it.

Comment: What database are you using? Some DBs have a hidden primary key that is autogenerated and hidden.

Comment: Why would you need an entity for that? That is just the table used on an `@ManyToMany` relation and you don't need a specific entity for that. Just a proper mapping in your `User` and `Role` entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the awnser in this post. This should help you.

[PK Explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29561919/10473718)

Another Option is if this is a join table, than you could make Embeded PK

```
@Embeddable
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class PersonGroupPK implements Serializable {
//default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(insertable=false,unique = false, updatable=false, nullable=false)
private Long personId;

@Column(insertable=false, unique = false,updatable=false, nullable=false)
private Long groupId;

}
```